# EBeans alternative to find() in JPA

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I was following the Play! Framework tutorial on creating a blog. They use JPA instead of EBeans and they use the find() function that extend from play.db.Jpa.Model . I am using EBeans and have extended with play.db.ebean.Model . However, when I use the find() function, it says that no such method exists. I have done some research and have looked here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/db/ebean/Model.html

and here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/db/ebean/Model.Finder.html

but there is no mention of a simple find() method (there are others such as findId() but I don't see how they can help). Is there an alternative I could use in the Model class? If not, are there any other classes that I could use easily?

**EDIT:**

The specific part I need to create is a connect() method in the User class. In the tutorial, this is described as:

```
In the User.java source, add the connect() method:

public static User connect(String email, String password) {
return find("byEmailAndPassword", email, password).first();
}
```

What other options do I have for this if I can't use find(). Will ebean.find() work?

Comment: What version of Play are you using? It sounds like you are looking at [this guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/guide2) for Play 1.2.x. In Play 2.3.x there is no JPA Model superclass anymore. For using Ebean queries [read here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaEbean) under *"Using the play.db.ebean.Model superclass"* for examples. For more also see the [Ebean docs](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery.html)

Comment: Yeah, I am using 2.2.x. I am trying to follow the tutorial loosely but replacing JPA with EBeans. It seems to be like I said though that you have to use find.byId or something similar. What can I use for the part of the tutorial you mention where I need find()? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I have been looking at the 'Ebean.find' in the docs that were linked. Is there any way I could use this? The examples are all for finding the order(?) and I can't find much info elsewhere on 'bean.find'.

Comment: `Ebean.find()` provides a fluent API for building queries pragmatically. However, if you're looking for a more SQL like approach then you can also pass in a query String. Look at the [last two examples in this doc](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery.html) for examples of both. If you add to your question more specifically what you want to do, I could help you with examples etc.

Comment: I am adding the specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of two methods of using find() method of the play.db.ebean.Model.
The first one goes like this:

```
User user = Ebean.find(User.class, id);
```

The second method would be something like this:

```
//define a Model.finder class in the User model class
 //The first parameter would be the datatype of the id used, which is String in my case
public static Model.Finder<String,User> find = new Model.Finder<String,User>(String.class, User.class);
User user = User.find.byId(id);
```

Since your query fetches data based on two values, your code should look something like this:

```
User.find.where()
            .eq("email", email).eq("password",password)
            .findUnique();
```